# Retrieve content of page by URL Parameter

Tags: content, post-content

There used to be a way of displaying only the content of a page, no other template features, by using a URL parameter.

I remember using this years ago, but I can't seem to find anything about this anymore

Comment: `www.yoururl/wp-json/wp/v2/`? Or using feed (rss).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, simply register your query:

```
function my_query($vars) {
    return array('your_query') + $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'my_query');
```

And get custom template the query exists (here `/?your_query=first` gets template called `custom_template.php` from your theme folder.

```
function my_query_template($template) {
  global $wp;
  if ($wp->query_vars['your_query']=='first') {
    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/custom_template.php';
  }
  else {
    return $template;
  }
}
add_filter('single_template', 'my_query_template');
```